# Who can access the data in the blockchain

Tags: blockchain, privacy

I have confused who can read the data in the public blockchain. If I publish a personal data belong to me to the blockchain, will it reveal to all nodes in the network?? Or only my self can read it but can't edit because I know blockchain is immutable.

what I really don't understand , if I send a secret key for node B, all nodes will know the key or only node B ??

If I put the address ( public key) of node B, that means who know the private key can read the message, am I right?? and in this case node B only will see the secret key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't put secret data in a public database.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, everyone can get the data from the blockchain.

For the private key and the public key, the public key acts as the middle bridge between the private key and the address, and his verification of the transaction is the most critical:

For the verification of a transaction, the role of the public key:

1. The public key generates an address, and verifies whether the address of the sent transaction is consistent with the address generated by the public key.
2. The public key verifies the signature of the private key to verify that the transaction is signed with the correct private key.
3. The private key generation public key appears in pairs, and the public key can generate a corresponding unique address, so that it can confirm whether the transaction sent by the address uses the corresponding private key.

The private key acts as a password, and only the private key can operate the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In classic blockchain concept the pair of keys are used for signing documents (transactions), not for encryption.

Usually:

- public key is used as user identifier
- private key is used to sign message (eg. I am transferring one coin to Alice)

Private key, like the name says, is private and You never should expose it to anybody.